# I can't make a reference

Tags: vim-latex

I'm new to latex so I'm trying to do the vim-latex tutorial. So now I'm supposed to make a reference. My file looks like:

```
%        File: package.tex
%     Created: Mon Feb 11 07:00 PM 2019 AST
% Last Change: Mon Feb 11 07:00 PM 2019 AST
%
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackagei[sublimitis,]{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  <e^{\pi} + 1 = 0>
  \label{eqn:euler}
\end{equation}
This is the famous euler equation. I will type another equation, just as true:
\begin{equation}
  \label{eqn:simple}
  1 + 1 = 2
\end{equation}
This is my contribution to mathematics.
This is a reference to (\ref{}).

\end{document}
```

With the cursor between the {} I pressed  in insert mode.
I'm supposed to see a list of all the \labels found in my project. But all I got is:

```
''C:' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to LaTeX at all. Consider asking at Vim.se.